# Extract the basic function from a model

Tags: r, model, equation, plm

In my thesis i estimated different "within" and "pooling" models using plm() of the plm package. Additionally, i modified some models by using a time lag. All the models work well and i got my results. Now i would like to visualize the models by showing their equation. So my question is:

Is there a way to extract the equation from the model?

I would need it in the most basic way, before any calculation is done.... [more or less like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXpZr.png)  because it is not about showing my results, but the math i use.

For my models i use a panel dataset and my models look more less like this (just more control variables).

`model1 <- plm (a ~ b + c, model = "within", data)`

Thank you

Comment: With  extract_eq() it should actually work for most models like glm() or lm() and some others.... As far as i understood the programs try to expand extract_eq() also for oder models, but plm() is not coverd jet

Comment: This could be about programming. Have a look at any textbook with panel data models for the general model equation of poooling and fixed effect models and you will be able to adapt those formulas to your models. I would assume you have read a textbook to come to the conclusion you want to estimate these models. Then copy, paste & adapt manually should be reasonable for any amount of models that are used within a thesis if there is no readily available function/package to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. The `formula` is embedded in the model object.

```
mod <- plm(mpg ~ hp,mtcars)

mod$call

data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

grun.fe <- plm(inv~value+capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within")

grun.fe$call
```

Also, check out equatiomatic to show the formula in latex:

https://datalorax.github.io/equatiomatic/index.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :) Sadly it seems that it doesnt work for plm.... it get the following error: > extract_eq(model1.1)
Error in UseMethod("extract_lhs", model) : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_lhs' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"